# I don't understand the difference between these two lines of code and why they return different results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't understand the difference between these two lines of code, and why they return different results when I use brackets.

```
df["Winner fav"] = (df["WPts"] - df["LPts"]).apply(lambda x: 1 if x>0 else 0)

df2["Winner fav"] = df2["WPts"] - df2["LPts"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>0 else 0)
```

Comment: Order of Operations is important for both MATH and PROGRAMMING. One word for you -- PEMDAS -- Think about this... what is the answer to `4 - 4 * 2` versus `(4 - 4) * 2`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations  *"In the United States, the acronym PEMDAS is common. It stands for Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplication/Division, Addition/Subtraction. PEMDAS is often expanded to the mnemonic "Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally""*

Answer (score 0):

It's an operator precedence issue.
The first one,

```
df["Winner fav"] = (df["WPts"] - df["LPts"]).apply(lambda x: 1 if x>0 else 0)
```

applies the `lambda` function on the difference of `df["WPts"] - df["LPts"]`.

The second one,

```
df2["Winner fav"] = df2["WPts"] - df2["LPts"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>0 else 0)
```

first applies the `lambda` on the value of `df2["LPts"]` and then subtracts 1 or 0 from `df2["WPts"]`

Comment: Ok.  Thanks very much for your answer!  Now it makes sense for me.